# Finding out if an entity has relations - How to?

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm trying to find out a way to find the relations of a specific entity, say one targeted for deletion.

Example setup:

- `Country` entity can have many `Currencies`.
- `Currency` entity can have `Countries`.
- A `Country` may have a primary `Currency`.

Therefore, the setup is: `Country <-> (1-n) <-> CountryCurrency <-> (n-1) <-> Currency`.

In the above example it's easy to find if a Country, targeted for deletion, has any associated Currencies.

However, imagine that the above is setup in a global kind of way and usable for other modules within the application.

If another module, `Address` for example, used a Country in a uni-directional relationship (an `Address` has one `Country`): *how can I figure out that the specific `Country` entity may not be deleted without trying to and thus receiving a `Foreign Key constraint` error*?

I'm hoping that Doctrine has something for this built in, but haven't been able to find it in the documentation. Have been Google'ing it for a while now as well without success. Always in the trend of: "well, you just `$entity->getSomeRelation()->count() > 0` and you know", but I'm looking for a generic solution/method that can apply to any entity.

Comment: Search for "php doctrine metadata".  The metadata describes all the relations.  I'm a bit skeptical as to how well your approach will actually work in practice but the info is there.

Comment: Interesting info, forgotten it was there. However, it's the wrong way for my use case. When applying it to the case in my question, I see all the info is there from the `Country` that I'm deleting. I see no results pertaining to the `Address` that uses the `Country` in its uni-directional relation. (As seen in the `ClassMetadata` entity in the `associationMappings` property -> contains links for `Country#coordinates` and `Country#countryCurrencies`). If you another idea, I'm all ears for pointers in the right direction.

Comment: I suppose you could try using the Doctrine Database Abstraction Layer schema tools to check for the existence of a foreign key constraint directly in the sql database. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/schema-manager.html  But I'm still dubious of your entire approach.  Do you really think you will run into this sort of problem?  How about just setting a configuration variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no generic solution for it because it always depends on your business model.

Deleting entity with relation can lead to different scenarios:

- deleting related entities as well
- setting the relation to null
- or disallow deleting at all.

So it's up to you to do the check mannualy, depending on your case.

Comment: Ah, but that's the thing. I'm am trying to create something that can work globally. Something along the lines of `$entity->isUsedByForeignKeys()` or `$entity->canBeDeleted()` or `$entity->hasAssociationsPointedAtIt()`. Something that does work globally because, it may have been written that way, checking in the way that MySQL does when (in my question example) you try to delete a `Country` that is used by `Address`, without the first knowing about the latter. If you have any pointers in that direction, I'm all ears.

Comment: I understand you, but I am afraid it's not a good direction:). If you really want to implement it I would recommend starting with doctrine metadata. You can retrieve information about all defined associations. When you have this data, you can build a list of entities you need to check for each entity. (building a list won't be a trivial operation, so you should cache it and make sure the cache is updated when your model has changed) Then write the function which checks it. You will likely face issues with composite keys, cascading operations, and performance. Good luck.